# Redirect to billing address form while clicking on back button in shipping method form in magento

Tags: magento-1.9

Redirect to billing address form while clicking on back button in shipping method form in magento 1.9 one page checkout. I want when user click on back button while user on shipping method rediect back to billing form rather to shipping address form. one page check

> login form
>
> billing address form > ship on same address checked.
>
> Shipping Method

When user click on back button from shipping method form, redirect to shipping method page but I want use get redirected to billing page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click on the back button in the onepage steps, you are calling a js prototype method `Checkout.prototype.back()` (see `skin/frontend/base/default/js/opcheckout.js:245`).

So, one way to modify the actual behaviour is to override this method :

1) If not already done, copy in your theme the file `app/design/frontend/base-or-rwd/default/template/checkout/onepage.phtml`. Then, after the line

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('js/opcheckout.js') ?>"></script>
```

Add the following line to add your own js file (that we will create soon) :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('js/opcheckout-override.js') ?>"></script>
```

2) In your theme, create the file `skin/frontend/<your-package>/<your-theme>/js/opcheckout-override.js`.

3) In this file, we have to override the `Checkout.prototype.back()` method. I did not test it but we could write something like :

```
Checkout.prototype.back = Checkout.prototype.back.wrap(function(parentMethod) {

    if (this.loadWaiting) return;

    if(this.currentStep == 'shipping_method'){
        this.changeSection('opc-billing');
    }
    else{
       parentMethod();
    }
});
```

Hope it helps.